# What does MOS 6507 do in Atari 2600 when you turn it on without a cartridge?

Tags: atari-2600, mos-650x

MOS 6500 family hardware manual says that during a reset (or a start up), processor will fetch program counter from addresses 0xFFFC and 0xFFFD. On Atari 2600 this memory region is mapped to ROM, once a cartridge is inserted.

What happens in the processor when you turn on Atari 2600 without cartridge? Will program counter fetch fail or will it fetch some garbage value? Will it try to decode an opcode or is there some safety feature to halt execution?

Comment: probably reads FF or 00

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the schematics

[image: Schematics for the Atari 2600]

These are the things on the data bus:

- The CPU (which the question is about)
- The ROM (which the question posits is not connected)
- The RIOT (a.k.a 6532)
- The TIA

The RIOT and TIA are both tristated when the CPU reads the reset vector or a (normal) instruction stream, which means the contents of the databus are not defined.

Therefore, the behavior of the Atari 2600 is not defined when there's not cartridge in on power-up. (The program counter will be set to some undefined value, and the CPU will proceed to execute from there. If the PC points to ROM, then the instructions fetched are also undefined, so there's no telling what it'll do. But it might also execute from the address space mapped to the RIOT or TIA).

Comment: There can be advantages to having a CPU bus float.  On the Apple II, if there are no cards with passive pull-ups or pull-downs, reading an open-bus address will yield the last byte fetched by the video hardware.  On the 2600, though I don't know of any cart designs that exploited this other than my own, it's possible to make a cart compatible with "normal" loads and stores, and even read-modify-write instructions, if on the first half of each cycle where it's accessed it performs a read of the appropriate address, and on the second half it writes whatever is on the data bus to RAM.

Comment: Seems like [6507](https://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/UMC/mXyztwtz.pdf) and [6532](https://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/480/501467_DS.pdf) pull up input-only pins, but that three-state data bus indeed has +- 10µA leakage so could float randomly.

Comment: @supercat You mean a cart that's able to mirror the RAM in the 6532? That would be quite amazing

Comment: Rather than a scenario, let's examine history instead. Atari built 30 million VCS consoles over about 14 years and there's no reports of substantial failures or degradation (noticeably shorter life) due to being powered on with no cartridge in. Or reports of any failures due to that. So there's no problem to solve, right?

Comment: @Героямслава: Prevention of undefined opcodes may have been important if one wanted to ensure that the system could be restored to useful operation *without having to remove power*.  If the 2600 is powered up without a cartridge, however, it will be necessary to remove power before use, whether or not there are pull-ups or pull-downs on the data bus.

Comment: @Героямслава: I designed a cart with 32K of RAM and 64K flash; if any part of RAM is banked into an area of address space, stores and read-modify-write instructions on that part of the address space will act upon the memory in the cart just like ordinary RAM.  By contrast, other RAM designs require using one set of addresses for reading and a different set of addresses for writing.

Comment: I'm afraid you're preoccupied with working backwards from the 'fun with circuits', trying to find a need, which there flatly isn't. But not working forwards from reqts, cost targets and business case to a circuit design. For a high-volume system with tight manf budget like the VCS, you really can't just throw in things on a whim. You haven't identified a business case as per my first comment. Justifying it technically is truly irrelevant, it needs a business justification, as all engineering does. Every single component weakens the product and must justify it's existence or not be there.

Comment: @Героямслава: It would have been widely recognized as impractical to ensure that reset would be asserted or the clock stopped at all times when a CPU might otherwise execute undefined opcodes.  Some chips such as flash memories do specify that undefined commands which are received when VDD is above a certain level may permanently alter device behavior, implying a need for voltage-monitor circuitry to block erroneous operation when power is lost, but in most cases there was a presumption that nothing that might occur while VDD was falling from 4.5V to 0V 
would have unacceptable consequences.